# Group DM Add Recipient "Missing Permissions"

Tags: node.js, api, discord, discord.js, channel

PUT/channels/{channel.id}/recipients/{user.id}
If i run this API then send me this permission issue
please help me
{
"message": "Missing Permissions",
"code": 50013
}

[Postman hit api screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk7CU.png)

Answer (score -2):

i have find the solution

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

```
  await guild.members.list();


  const channel = await guild.channels.create({
    name: channelName,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: guild.roles.everyone,
        deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      },
      {
        id: memberId,
        allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log(`Channel created: ${channel}`);
```